# Change tag 'metric' into 'metric-distance'

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Many newcomer users incorrectly apply tag 'metric' (defined as a subclass of distances) to questions where word "a metric" is used by them simply as "a coefficient", "a  measure".

So please create tag 'metric-distance' and make tag 'metric' a junior synonym of it.

Comment: I might prefer `[distance-metric]`, dunno, but otherwise, absolutely.

Comment: Do you mean the $d$ on the metric space $(M, d)$ as opposed to a metric like the AUC of a machine learning model?

Comment: @Dave, yes, our current tag 'metric' is specifically for this, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics). A distance satisfying the metricity axioms.

Comment: Looking at some of the questions tagged with metric it seems relatively few of them are about metric in the sense intended so it might almost be better to give up and rename it distance.

Comment: @mdewey:  and everybody: I will have a look!